# Why is paint(Graphics g) not getting called from child JComponent?

Tags: java, swing, paint, java-2d

I'm having a simple `JComponent` that functions as a `PdfPage` but is basically just a rendered `Image`.

However, this `PdfPage` is supposed to hold `Highlight` annotations e.g. to mark an error inside a PDF Document.

`Highlight` is just another `JComponent` that is just painting itself as a rectangle:

```
public class Highlight extends JComponent {

    private Rectangle rectangle;
    private Color borderColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
    private Color fillColor;

    public Highlight(Rectangle rectangle, Color fillColor) {
        this.rectangle = rectangle;
        this.fillColor = fillColor;     
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(this.fillColor);
        g.fillRect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width, rectangle.height);

        g.setColor(this.borderColor);
        g.drawRect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
    }
}
```

The problem is that adding a `Highlight` to a `PdfPage` does not cause it to be painted:

```
    for (DatasheetError datasheetError : datasheetErrorList) {

        Highlight highlight = createErrorHighlight(datasheetError); 

        int pageNumber = datasheetError.getPage() - 1;
        PdfPage pdfPage = pdfPages[pageNumber];
        pdfPage.add(highlight); 
        pdfPage.repaint()      // Does not help here!
        pdfPage.invalidate();  // Does not help here!
    }
```

That is why I have a loop over all child `Component` objects of a `PdfPage` and call `paint(Graphics g)` on each inside `PdfPage` which looks like this:

```
public class PdfPage extends JComponent {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        // Paint the pdf page ..
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        if (pageImage != null) {
            int x = 0, y = 0, width = pageImage.getWidth(null), height = pageImage.getHeight(null); 
            g.drawImage(pageImage, x, y, width, height, null);
        }

        // Paint all child components such as "Highlight"
        for(Component component : this.getComponents()) {
            component.paint(g);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this how I am supposed to do that or is there a better way to draw child components of that `PdfPage`? I have tried to call `repaint()` and `invalidate()` on each `PdfPage` but that didn't work.

Why doesn't the `pain(Graphics g)` method get called from each `Highlight`? Can I put that in execution somehow?

Comment: For `JComponent` you are supposed to override the `paintComponent` method, not the `paint` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to paint components directly, that is the job of Swing. Get rid of the code attempting to paint the highlights from the PdfPage class.

When you add components to a container, the child components are painted by the `paintChildren(...)` method. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) for more information.

As mentioned in the comment, custom painting is done in the `paintComponent()` method. In your case you override paint() but don't invoke super.paint() so the paintChildren() method is never invoked so the child components don't get painted.

However when you fix this, a JComponent does not use a layout manager so when you add components to your PdfPage class they will not be painted. So, you need to specify the size and location of the components. In your case is looks like the size/location would be based on the Rectangle.

So fix the code and let the normal Swing painting mechanism work instead of trying to do it yourself.

Or a different approach, if you want to do custom painting, would be to have an `addHighlight(...)` as a method of your `PdfPage` class. Then in this case you would keep a list of Rectangles that you want to paint and iterate through this list in the `paintComponent()` method of the PdfPage clase. Check out the`DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example of this approach.

Comment: One more thing.. as the PDF page is actually just a `Image`, where would I paint that? Since this is not a component but represents the actual page, would it be okay to use `paint(Graphics g)` to paint the `Image` and `paintComponent()` to draw the highlights?

Comment: @StefanFalk, You can display an image in a JLabel using an ImageIcon. Then you just add the label to the GUI like any other component. Check out the table of contents of the tutorial link I provided. There is also a section on `How to Use Labels`.